# String pluralizer with NSNumberFormatter

Tags: ios, localization, nsnumberformatter, pluralize

I want to display a nicely formatted integer value via the usual pluralization technology `.stringsdict` file. (Apple docs [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/StringsdictFileFormat/StringsdictFileFormat.html))

So if I have one thing, I want my output to read

> 1 thing

But if I have two thousand, three hundred sixty-four things, I want those commas:

> 2,364 things

but alas the string pluralization technology doesn't give them to me:

> 2364 things

I can achieve commas with an [`NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter). I can achieve  pluralization with `.stringsdict` localization technology.

Can I easily achieve both?

Comment: Update your question to include the code you have at the moment to get the localized string with the number.

Comment: @rmaddy nah, anybody who can help will know what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have `.stringsdict` files setup with the properly plural strings, you don't actually need a number formatter. Simply use the `localizedStringWithFormat` method of `String` or `NSString`.

Assuming you have setup the localized key `"%d things"` in your Localizable.strings files and your `.stringsdict` files, your code would look something like:

Swift:

```
let things = 2364
let localizedString = String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString(@"%d things", @"Your comment"), things)
```

Objective-C:

```
int things = 2364;
NSString *localizedString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%d things", @"Your comment"), things];
```

Depending on your locale, the result will be something like:

> 2,364 things
>   2.364 things
>   2 364 things

Comment: I already got serial up voted in the last 24-hours so please don't try. :)